# How to create an image tag cloud

Tags: jquery, css, image, image-processing, tag-cloud

I would like to create a tag cloud but using images.

I don't mind how I achieve this, whether it is with a JQuery plugin, css or some clever programming.

I came across a jquery plugin called image tag cloud, but seems unsupported and well generally not working.

Anyone got ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I never found an existing implementation for this, but one would need to implement some sort of [packing algorythm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something:

Flex

A fluid asymmetrical animated grid plugin for jQuery

http://jsonenglish.com/projects/flex/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

[Algorithm to implement a word cloud like Wordle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342687/algorithm-to-implement-a-word-cloud-like-wordle)

The "DisOrganizer" mentioned in the answers could serve your purpose. With a little change, you can let this "Disorganizer" to serve an image, the way you wanted. PS: The code is written in C#
https://github.com/chandru9279/zasz.me/blob/master/zasz.me/