# WPF User Control String Scaling

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a user control which takes some strings and displays them in the UI according to how many times the string appears in my collection. Therefore the more times a string is contained in my collection then the larger it would appear in the UI and vice versa. Anyway my problem is that at the moment a scrollViewer is displaying the tags but I would like all the tags to be displayed in one window without the need for scrolling and also scale to fit the whole window. Can anyone assist with this? thanks!

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="TagCloudDemo.TagCloudControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:TagCloudDemo="clr-namespace:TagCloudDemo">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <TagCloudDemo:WeightToSizeConverter x:Key="WeightToSizeConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>

<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tags, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TagCloudDemo:TagCloudControl}}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="{Binding Path=Weight, Converter={StaticResource WeightToSizeConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

**Code behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace TagCloudDemo
{
    public partial class TagCloudControl : UserControl
    {
        public TagCloudControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> Words
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable<string>)GetValue(WordsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(WordsProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty WordsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Words", 
                                        typeof(IEnumerable<string>), 
                                        typeof(TagCloudControl), 
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(new List<string>(), WordsChanged));

        public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags
        {
            get { return (IEnumerable<Tag>)GetValue(TagsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TagsProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TagsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Tags", 
                                        typeof(IEnumerable<Tag>), 
                                        typeof(TagCloudControl),
                                        new UIPropertyMetadata(new List<Tag>(), TagsChanged));

        private static void WordsChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TagCloudControl tagCloudControl = sender as TagCloudControl;
            tagCloudControl.Tags = TagCloudDemo.Tag.CreateTags(tagCloudControl.Words);
        }

        private static void TagsChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TagCloudControl tagCloudControl = sender as TagCloudControl;
            WeightToSizeConverter converter = tagCloudControl.FindResource("WeightToSizeConverter") as WeightToSizeConverter;
            if (converter != null && tagCloudControl.Tags != null)
            {
                converter.MaxWeight = tagCloudControl.Tags.Max(t => t.Weight);
            }
        }
    }

    public class WeightToSizeConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public int MaxWeight { get; set; }

        #region IValueConverter Members
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int weight = (int)value;
            return 32 * MaxWeight / weight;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        #endregion IValueConverter Members
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is something like wordle.net produces then you need to use a canvas and position each tag using some algorithm which will minimize space between each tag, see [Algorithm to implement something like Wordle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342687/algorithm-to-implement-something-like-wordle). This will be some hard code to write.

A simpler solution would be to use a wrappanel and put inside a viewbox. Add below code to your itemscontrol. This is the solution I have seen others use who created tag cloud controls and published their code, for example: [Creating a Tag Cloud in Silverlight](http://jomit.blogspot.com/2008/12/creating-tag-cloud-in-silverlight.html)

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Hi, I decided to try and write an algorithm to solve this problem. Please see my lastest question: WPF custom panel scaling to fit window. Thanks - ben

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`ViewBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx) instead of a `ScrollViewer` to wrap your tag cloud.

Comment: Problem with that is that it will cut off some tags when they no longer fit the window.