# Advanced Wordle-like computation

Tags: graphics

I've seen [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342687/algorithm-to-implement-a-word-cloud-like-wordle) about a Wordle-like algorithm. It's really great and interessant but the proposed open-source libraries, just like Wordle, are kind of limited.

For instance, how do I do something like the picture below given a shape and words with some "weight". I mean of course programmatically so using snippets or libraries.

[image: Type poster]

Comment: First, realize that the reference image pixels can be reduced to blocks of color that can still render the image, matching the blocks size to color. Second list your words by weight. Match color to weight ... and viola ...

Answer (score 0):

I imagine if you had some code which can handle text layout so that words don't intersect each other (wordle is [an excellent example of this](http://static.mrfeinberg.com/bv_ch03.pdf) of course), it's not too difficult to add some extra line-art/polygon shapes as input and have the text layout take that into consideration too.