# Graph of word frequencies

Tags: word-frequency, word-cloud

[image]

I want to make a function which from a text input produces a word frequency graph like this in the picture. This picture is taken from a report, so I am not sure how they have made it.

Answer (score 1):

There's much more work here that a single function. The following links contain code of projects that perform similar tasks. You could reuse them in your program.

1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224231/Word-Cloud-Tag-Cloud-Generator-Control-for-NET-Win
2. [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19968/WordCloud-A-Squarified-Treemap-of-Word-
   Frequency](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19968/WordCloud-A-Squarified-Treemap-of-Word-Frequency)
3. https://github.com/whydoidoit/WordCloud (Silverlight)

Also, check out the accepted answer of [Algorithm to implement a word cloud like Wordle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342687/algorithm-to-implement-a-word-cloud-like-wordle), it's an answer by the creator of Wordle in which he explain the basic algorithm.